# TypeError: str.charAt is not a function: at parse (/app/node_modules/pg-connection-string/index.js:13:11) Heroku Addons postgresql

Tags: javascript, html, postgresql, heroku

when I run deploy my app to heroku I got this error

```html
2022-05-26T01:38:34.587567+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: str.charAt is not a function
2022-05-26T01:38:34.587577+00:00 app[web.1]: at parse (/app/node_modules/pg-connection-string/index.js:13:11)
2022-05-26T01:38:34.587577+00:00 app[web.1]: at new ConnectionParameters (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection-parameters.js:56:42)
2022-05-26T01:38:34.587578+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Client (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:19:33)
2022-05-26T01:38:34.587579+00:00 app[web.1]: at BoundPool.newClient (/app/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:213:20)
2022-05-26T01:38:34.587579+00:00 app[web.1]: at BoundPool.connect (/app/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:207:10)
2022-05-26T01:38:34.587579+00:00 app[web.1]: at BoundPool.query (/app/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:389:10)
2022-05-26T01:38:34.587580+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.exports.getUserByEmail (/app/server/db/postgresql/queries.js:57:6)
2022-05-26T01:38:34.587580+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/server/routes/api/user.js:32:38
2022-05-26T01:38:34.587580+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2022-05-26T01:38:34.587581+00:00 app[web.1]: at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
```

although it is works fine on my localhost and heroku local.

```html
exports.getUserByEmail = async (email) => {
  let user = "";
  await pool
    .query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = $1", [email])
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.rows[0]) {
        user = res.rows[0].email;
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      throw e;
    });

  return user;
};
```

```html
user.js

 try {
        let payload = {};
        const user = await poolQuery.getUserByEmail(email);
        if (user) {
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ errors: [{ msg: "User already exists" }] });
        } else {
          const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
          const encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
```

Both email and password from the user.js is a string. Only the res returned from the query is object but I also casted it into a string. So do not know where is the issue.

My connectionString config

```html
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
require("dotenv").config();

const devConfig = `postgresql://${process.env.PG_USER}:${process.env.PG_PASSWORD}@${process.env.PG_HOST}:${process.env.PG_PORT}/${process.env.PG_DATABASE}`;

const proConfig = {
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
};

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString:
    process.env.NODE_ENV == "production" ? proConfig : devConfig,
});

exports.pool = pool;
```

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: a wild guess, but is `password` a string? to be honest, it's kinda hard to see which line of your code results in the error - looks like `/app/server/routes/api/user.js:32:38` but which line is that?

Comment: @Bravo Good idea, wrong target: the error is generated from `getUserByEmail`, in the `query` line. So... a wild guess, but is `email` a string?

Comment: Password is a string and the error exists in the line const user = await poolQuery.getUserByEmail(email);. The getuserbyemail is the query from the postgreSQL. First time posting a question so im sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Amadan - lol, yeah, I didn't read the error message properly - it's right there, isn't it :p

Comment: Actually, reading a bit deeper, it seems the problem might be in connection parameters. Is this the first query your code is making to the database? How is `pool` initialised? What are the variables involved there?

Comment: @Amadan 
This is how my pool connection string
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
require("dotenv").config();

const devConfig = `postgresql://${process.env.PG_USER}:${process.env.PG_PASSWORD}@${process.env.PG_HOST}:${process.env.PG_PORT}/${process.env.PG_DATABASE}`;

const proConfig = {
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
};

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString:
    process.env.NODE_ENV == "production" ? proConfig : devConfig,
});

exports.pool = pool;

This is not a first query in the codebase , however it is a first queries get called from the logic.

Answer (score 1):

When `NODE_ENV=production`, you end up with

```
{
  connectionString: {
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  }
}
```

which doesn't look right at all. This also explains why you get the issue on Heroku and not locally (where you are presumably using a dev environment). Try to fix `proConfig` as follows:

```
const proConfig = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
```